# My webview is opening the webpage in the default browser

Tags: android, webview

So I just implemented a simple webview application in which i was loading the stackoverflow main page. Earlier it was working just fine but now as I click on some link it opens that link in the default browser. I have implemented and override the shouldoverrideUrlLoading method by creating my custom webViewClient class. 
I know that there are various question ask like these but I am writing this question only because they don't work for me.

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith(".com"))
            return false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        final customEditText editText = findViewById(R.id.urlEditText);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.enterButtonId);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.loadUrl("https://"+editText.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
*`webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("url");`*
Just implement the web client and set it before loadUrl. The simplest way is:

`WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: I have implemented this. You have to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading( ) method for your webview to open the website in your webview. If we don't override this, then definitely the default browser will be open when we link on any link on the loaded Url.

Answer (score 0):

So When I was reading a tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/9333/android-webview-example-tutorial in this it is given that when shouldOverrideUrlLoading( ) method provides false then it url opens in our webview and if it returns true, then it will not load the page at all. So I think that earlier my code was working was because I was opening .com extensioned websites but when i open other extension website then it redirect to the default browser.